# Problem with Timestamp using .Net entity framework and Devart dotConnect for MySQL

Tags: .net, mysql, entity-framework, devart

I have the following table in my MySQL database :

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Benutzer (

  Id            INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY     AUTO_INCREMENT,

  Login         VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,

  Nachname      VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,

  Vorname       VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,

  Timestamp     TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

)`

In my Visual Studio 2010-edmx the field Timestamp has the following atrributes:

`StoreGeneratedPattern: Computed

Type: DateTime`

On inserting a new record into the table I get the following exception:

Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlException: Incorrect datetime value: '0001-01-01 00:00:00' for column 'Timestamp' at row 1.

I need the Timestamp-field to handle concurrency issues.

Version of Devart.Data.MySql.Entity is 6.0.86.0.
Im am using Visual Studio 2010 and .Net Runtime 3.5 Sp1.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: post the generated mysql query

Comment: insert into anlaufmanagement.benutzer(Login, Nachname, Vorname, `Timestamp`)
values ('xxx', 'lastname', 'firstname', '0001-01-01 00:00:00')
;select Id
from anlaufmanagement.benutzer
where Id = last_insert_id()

Comment: The problem seems to be, that mysql is not able to handle 0001-01-01 00:00:00 as Timestamp.

Comment: Only the insert statement causes this problem, updates are working.

Comment: we have replied you at our forum here http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=19995

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should IGNORE update this DateTime field by EntityFramework.
Just let database handle its value update automatically.

It seems EntityFramework give a default value to DateTime field which is "0001-01-01 00:00:00", it's the default behavior of .NET.

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }
```

Use above annotation will tell EF to ignore the CreateDate when make changes to the entity.